# Manifest malformed?

Tags: java, android, manifest

Ive got error "manifest malformes" when I install app. How to repair this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.barwnikk.android.l2sd"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="8" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MainActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:process=".OnModifyApp" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `android:name="something"` in the `<receiver />`.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
 <receiver
        android:process=".OnModifyApp" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

to

```
<receiver
        android:name=".OnModifyApp" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need     `android:name` field instead of `android:process` in the `receiver` tag

Answer (score 0):

For me it was the problem with the meta-data, where I added the 'usb.attached' thingy. Deleting that line fixed the error.